# How to initialize a node with data

Tags: corda

How can I initialize a node with data?

Let's take the bootcamp's application as an example. There you can issue tokens to other parties.

I want to extend that, and check if the sending node, has the tokens in the first place. Only if he has the tokens, he can give them to another party.

The problem is that the sender doesn't have any tokens. How can I set a specific amount of tokens to the sender? Is there any other method besides self-issuing the tokens first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to initialise the node with certain transactions already completed.

Instead, you'd have to write a small client that you'd execute after creating the node to automatically perform the transaction(s) you want. In the case of the Bootcamp CorDapp, you might write something like:

```
public class Client {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Client.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        // Create an RPC connection to the node.
        if (args.length != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: Client <node address> <rpc username> <rpc password>");
        final NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = parse(args[0]);
        final String rpcUsername = args[1];
        final String rpcPassword = args[2];
        final CordaRPCClient client = new CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress);
        final CordaRPCOps proxy = client.start(rpcUsername, rpcPassword).getProxy();

        // Issue the tokens.
        Party owner = proxy.nodeInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0);
        int amount = 100;
        proxy.startFlowDynamic(TokenIssueFlow.class, owner, amount).getReturnValue().get();
    }
}
```